# details not showing cakephp and ajax used

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

i have addend action and its view in which i have 4 select option city, speciality, hospital, doctor. now i need that as soon as i select the last option ajax call will run and on the same page all the details above including doctors visitdays, from and to_time dynamically from the database.
DoctorScheduleend() action view not created!
i have this code but coudn't find where is the problem is!
plz have patience and help me out guys pls!

**model:**

```
<?php 
class DoctorSchedule extends AppModel {
    public $name='DoctorSchedule';
    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A State Name is required'
            )
        ),
        'country_id' => array('notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please Select Country'
        ),
        )
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Doctor' => array(
            'className' => 'Doctor',
            "foreignKey" => 'doctor_id'
        ),
            'Office' => array(
            'className' => 'Office',
            "foreignKey" => 'office_id'
        )
    );
```

**EnduserController::doctorscheduleend()**

```
public function doctorscheduleend()
        {
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->loadModel('DoctorSchedule');
            $this->loadModel('Doctor');
            $this->loadModel('Office');

            $doctor_name = $this->Doctor->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Doctor.first_name','Doctor.last_name'),'conditions'=>array('Doctor.id'=>$_POST['DoctorId'])));
            $this->set('doctor_name',$doctor_name);

            foreach($doctor_name as $row)
            {
                $doctor_first_name = $row['Doctor']['first_name'];
                $doctor_last_name = $row['Doctor']['last_name'];
            }

            $schedule = $this->DoctorSchedule->find('all',array('fields'=>array('DoctorSchedule.office_id','DoctorSchedule.visitdays','DoctorSchedule.from_time','DoctorSchedule.to_time'),'conditions'=>array('DoctorSchedule.doctor_id'=>$_POST['DoctorId'])));
            $office_id  = $visitdays = $from_time  = $to_time = $officename= "";

            foreach($schedule as $row)
            {
                $office_id  = $row['DoctorSchedule']['office_id'];
                $visitdays  = $row['DoctorSchedule']['visitdays'];
                $from_time  = $row['DoctorSchedule']['from_time'];
                $to_time    = $row['DoctorSchedule']['to_time'];
            }

            $office = $this->Office->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Office.office_name'),'conditions'=>array('Office.id'=>$office_id)));/*editted here $officeid to ['$office_id']*/
            $this->set('officename', $office);
            foreach($office as $row)
            {
                $officename = $row['Office']['office_name'];
            }

            $tablerows = "";
            $tablerows.= "<tr>
                            <td colspan='4' style='color:white;'>Schedule Of Dr. ".$doctor_first_name." ".$doctor_last_name."</td>
                          </tr></br>

                          <tr>
                            <th width='20%' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#0c884b'>Hospital</th>
                            <th width='20%' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#0c884b'>Visitday</th>
                            <th width='20%' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#0c884b'>From</th>
                            <th width='20%' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#0c884b'>To</th>
                          </tr></br>

                          <tr>
                            <td>".$officename."</td>
                            <td>".$visitdays."</td>
                            <td>".$from_time."</td>
                            <td>".$to_time."</td>
                          </tr>";

            echo $tablerows;
        }
```

**ajax query:**

```
$('#DoctorId').on('change',function()
            {
                if($('#CityId').val()!='')
                {
                    if($('#SpecialtyId').val()!='')
                    {
                        if($('#OfficeId').val()!='')
                        {
                            $.ajax(
                            {
                                dataType: 'text',
                                cache: 'false',
                                url:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Enduser','action'=>'doctorscheduleend'));?>',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data : {"DoctorId": $('#DoctorId').val()},
                                evalScripts : true,
                                success: function (response)
                                {
                                    var y = document.getElementById("ScheduleList").rows.length;
                                    if(y!=0)
                                    {
                                        for(var i=0;i<1;i++)
                                        {
                                            $('#ScheduleList tr').remove();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $('#ScheduleList').append(response);
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                                {
//                                  showMessage("Error in ajax call.", 'error');
                                }
                            });                  
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps:

Step 1: Check ajax request using firbug in mozilla firefox

```
http://localhost/YOUR URL
    Check response
```

Step 2: If it is completing sucessfully then check, what is the output, is it the same output you want or something else.
Step 3: If desired out put check update divs and javascript code.
Step 4: If output is incorrect debug the proceessing at micro level, for example introduce echo after every line then check.....